# Delete comments from xml file while parsing it using libxml

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, libxml2

Following is the XML file with one of its node(i.e. `<date>`) being commented.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<story>
  <info>
    <author>Abc Xyz</author>
    <!--<date>June 2, 2017</date> -->
    <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  </info>
</story>
```

What I want is to remove that commented line/node completely from the XML file using libxml library and it should look as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<story>
  <info>
    <author>Abc Xyz</author>
    <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  </info>
</story>
```

I also referred the libxml documentation but that didn't helped me much with the "comment/s" in XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in a different way and it worked. Looks like using `xmlreader` for modifying the xml will not help much, instead I did `xmlReadMemory()`, then while parsing did following check:

```
if(node->type == XML_COMMENT_NODE){ //node is of type xmlNodePtr
    xmlUnlinkNode(node);
    xmlFreeNode(node);
}
```

And finally `xmlDocDumpFormatMemory()` to store the modified xml in `xmlbuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NodeType()` while parsing the xml and check for each node if it’s a comment (8 means comment, see here: http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html#Extracting) and then remove it with `xmlUnlinkNode()` and `xmlFreeNode()`.